# How to configure to a role group in LdapExtLoginModule in JBOSS EAP 6.3?

Tags: jboss

Some one in our company has configured to almost all the role groups using LdapExtLoginModule in JBOSS EAP 6.3 and that is working fine.Here is the standalone-full.xml file with that configuration:

```
<security-domain name="LDAPAuthentication" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://ha-adds-global.xxxx.com:3268"/>
            <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=prodjbsvc,OU=SvcAccounts,OU=NOPOL,dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
            <module-option name="bindCredential" value="XQtU@1lc"/>
            <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
            <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=COSAs,dc=eagle,dc=xxxx,dc=com"/>
            <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
            <module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
            <module-option name="roleRecursion" value="-1"/>
            <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
            <module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
            <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I want to configure the LDAP server to only a particular role group - "ALL_CONTRACTORS", in such a way that only contractors should be able to login to this security domain. For which I changed the standalone-full.xml "rolesCtxDN" attribute value to:

```
<module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=ALL_CONTRACTORS,OU=GROUPS,OU=SMO,OU=COSAs,DC=eagle,DC=xxxx,DC=com"/>
```

But it did not make any difference. I can login with using any of the user credentials from the LDAP server. Can anyone help me with my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Role search context is not related to authentication, but authorization. So if you really want to limit login only to users with the given role, you have to change the **`baseFilter`** login module option:

```xml
<module-option name="baseFilter" 
    value="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=ALL_CONTRACTORS,OU=GROUPS,OU=SMO,OU=COSAs,DC=eagle,DC=xxxx,DC=com))"/>
```

Comment: That worked. I just made one small correction. We cannot use "&" directly into the baseFilter value. Instead I used "&amp;" Thank you @kwart

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the ampersand issue. I've fixed it in the answer.

Comment: I know this question/answer is a few years old, but I've spent the last 2 days pulling my hair out over this and after coming across this question, I have it working within minutes.